# Using mod rewrite to rewrite a particular url string in codeigniter

Tags: apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm not sure if mod rewrite should be used here:

I'd like to rewrite one url:

```
www.baseurl.com/url-with-hyphens
```

to:

```
 www.baseurl.com/controller/method
```

This is a codeigniter application, here are my current rules:

```
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
            RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I have tried:

```
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
            RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
            RewriteRule ^.registration/available/2 /u-s-course-schedules/
```

Thanks